# When building Java RESTful Service, what has bigger advantages - to create POJOs or XML documents for them first?

Tags: java, xml, rest, methodology

For instance, when I know how all representations should look like, which path has more advantages.

1. Creating/Annotating Java classes and then document them in (lets say) XML documentations.
2. Write XML representation and then generate Java classes.

From what I may think of:

First approach would increase development speed. Since documentation is the last step (when it's feasible).

Second approach may let me feel as I am the client (for my own App) and will lead me to consider, how practical is my representation from a user standpoint.

But I have no other ideas, while I assume that this topic might be important in some cases, that I just don't know yet.

Comment: Okay, JSON, not XML. =) Lets say whatever 'standard' representation format, accepted by developers, who use whatever programming language.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is "it depends".

I've written quite a lot of REST services and I stick by very simple rules:

1. If this is a public facing API and by public I mean that you do not control all the clients consuming it, or once they're released they're in the wild then I will write the API first and make my Java model fit into that
2. If it's purely internal and you have the ability to change at will then go for the Java model first and just use whatever representation gets spit out.

The latter is the faster development model but it relies on you not really caring about what the actual representation looks like.

Comment: As someone who made services both ways I agree with this answer. If you care about your service signature and don't want some transient attribute added later on a POJO class being exposed go by the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Java POJO's can easily be serialized to xml so I would generate the xml from existing java POJOS (although I agree with the commenter json is usually better)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for POJOs like ghostbust555. The reason for that is XML is just one of many serialization formats. You could JSON or even your proprietary text format (or binary format).

If you take plain POJOs you can then annotate them for XML marshalling / unmarshalling via JAXB for instance. You could also use them for binary protocols such as Apache Thrift.

Lastly you could actually start from a UML class diagram and use that to generate your POJOs. That helps you document your model better.

Answer (score -1):

creating POJOs is better then XML documents.